# JavaFX visualise Stars

Tags: java, javafx

I am currenty building an Supermarket using JavaFX. Each item in the supermarket has multiple ranting for example. An apple has 3,8 out of 5 possible stars.
I found libraries can visualise only hole stars.

Do you guys know a library that can visulize half or even 8/10 stars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Filling `SVGPath` with colors and linear gradients

For the integer part, it is very easy; we iterate and fill the shape with just one color. But it's a little bit tricky for the floating part. You need to convert that floating part in percentage (the transparent part is the subtract to complete 100%) e.g. 80% color (0.8) and 20% transparent (1.0 - 0.2).

This is a single class JavaFX app you can try:

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Star[] stars = {new Star(), new Star(), new Star(), new Star(), new Star()};

        Label label = new Label();
        HBox box = new HBox(stars);
        box.getChildren().add(label);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        setRating(2.2f, label, stars);
        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(box), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private void setRating(Float value, Label label, Star[] stars) {
        for (Star star : stars)
            star.clearStar();

        int intPart = value.intValue();
        float floatPart = value - intPart;

        for (int i = 0; i < intPart; i++)
            stars[i].setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);

        if (floatPart >= 0.5)
            stars[intPart].setStyle("-fx-fill:linear-gradient(to right, yellowgreen "
                    + floatPart * 100 + "%, transparent "
                    + 100 * (1 - floatPart) + "%) ;");

        else
            stars[intPart].setStyle("-fx-fill:linear-gradient(to left, transparent "
                    + 100 * (1 - floatPart)+ "%, yellowgreen "
                    +  floatPart * 100 + "%) ;");
        
        label.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    class Star extends SVGPath {
        public Star() {
            this.setContent("M26.285,2.486l5.407,10.956c0.376,0.762,1.103,1.29,1.944,"
                    + "1.412l12.091,1.757  c2.118,0.308,2.963,2.91,1.431,4.403l-8.749,8.528c"
                    + "-0.608,0.593-0.886,1.448-0.742,2.285l2.065,12.042  c0.362,2.109-1.852,"
                    + "3.717-3.746,2.722l-10.814-5.685c-0.752-0.395-1.651-0.395-2.403,0l-10.814,5.685"
                    + "  c-1.894,0.996-4.108-0.613-3.746-2.722l2.065-12.042c0.144-0.837-0.134-1.692"
                    + "-0.742-2.285l-8.749-8.528  c-1.532-1.494-0.687-4.096,1.431-4.403l12.091-1.757c0.841"
                    + "-0.122,1.568-0.65,1.944-1.412l5.407-10.956  C22.602,0.567,25.338,0.567,26.285,2.486z");
            setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        }

        public void clearStar() {
            setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            getStyleClass().clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]